# Save an interaction plot (plotweb) with loop in R

Tags: for-loop, plot, save, bipartite

I am trying to save interactions plots (plotweb) via a loop, in order to save 1 graph for each site (in this test dataset, there are 3).
The loop seems to work and generates the 3 graphs I want, but I cannot save them.
I have already tried with 'ggsave()' and here is my code with the simple 'svg()' command but the saved graphs are empty...
Do you have a solution? :)

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11rqF.png)

```
for (x in levels(test_sum$Site)) {
  plot_nw <- plotweb(test_sum %>%
                       filter (Site == x) %>% 
                       filter(sum!=0) %>% 
                       select(Sp_Pollinisateurs,Sp_Plantes,sum) %>% 
                       arrange(Sp_Pollinisateurs) %>% 
                       pivot_wider(names_from = Sp_Pollinisateurs,
                                   values_from = sum,
                                   values_fill = 0) %>% 
                       select(where(~ any(. != 0))) %>% 
                       arrange(Sp_Plantes) %>% 
                       as.data.frame() %>%
                       select(-Site) %>% 
                       column_to_rownames(var="Sp_Plantes"), 
                     text.rot = 90,
                     y.lim = c(-0.55, 4))
  svg(paste0("Output/myplot_", x, ".svg")) # ouvrir le fichier SVG
  print(plot_nw) # imprimer le graphique
  dev.off() # fermer le fichier SVG
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put the svg() line before the plotweb line

```
for (x in levels(loop_sum$Site_gestion_date_Quadrat)) {
  svg(paste0("Output/Reseaux_loop/", x, ".svg")) # ouvrir le fichier SVG
  plot_nw <- plotweb(loop_sum %>% 
                       filter(Site_gestion_date_Quadrat == x) %>% 
                       filter(sum!=0) %>% 
                       select(Sp_Pollinisateurs,Sp_Plantes,sum) %>% 
                       arrange(Sp_Pollinisateurs) %>% 
                       pivot_wider(names_from = Sp_Pollinisateurs,
                                   values_from = sum,
                                   values_fill = 0) %>% 
                       select(where(~ any(. != 0))) %>% 
                       arrange(Sp_Plantes) %>% 
                       as.data.frame() %>%
                       select(-Site_gestion_date_Quadrat) %>% 
                       column_to_rownames(var="Sp_Plantes"), 
                     text.rot = 90,
                     y.lim = c(-0.55, 4))
  plot_nw # imprimer le graphique
  dev.off() # fermer le fichier SVG
}
```